# How do I get the bold hour back?

Tags: home-screen, clock

The clock on the previous Android had the hour displayed with bold text. Is there any way to get it back?

Comment: Please update to share which device, Android Version, and what Home Page/Launcher you have?

Comment: And please indicate which clock you're referring to: the one on the lock screen, on the status bar, on your home screen... In the latter case it might also be important to know where you took that from (stock widget?).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here, because you're missing some crucial information in your question, but...

The clock has been completely redesigned in [Android 4.4](http://www.android.com/versions/kit-kat-4-4/). Here's a comparison I found on [in a post on Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/10/31/apk-download-android-4-4-clockalarmtimerstopwatch-app-with-fixed-font-four-tabs-new-time-picker-and-more/).

[image: clock widget, Android 4.3]

[image: clock widget, Android 4.4]

You won't be able to change it on the stock clock. However, you can easily find yourself an alternate clock in the Play Store. (Here's just two I found: [Jelly Bean Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.com.breaker.jelly.bean.clock) and [Clock JB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moblynx.clockjb). There are dozens of others.)